# Query error IN GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want only one `F_LATPRIMI`, `F_LONPRIMI` from any `I_ID_NAVE`

```
select  I_ID_NAVE  ,F_LATPRIMI ,F_LONPRIMI
from(
    select 
        distinct imo,[N_ident_seguenziale]
    from    
        navi  
        inner join
        [ESTERNALIZZAZIONE_FASCICOLINAVE]
    ON
        [ESTERNALIZZAZIONE_FASCICOLINAVE].[I_ID_NAVE]=navi.[N_ident_seguenziale]
) as tabimo
inner join
    posizioni 
    on
    posizioni.[I_ID_NAVE]=tabimo.[N_ident_seguenziale] 

 where 
     DATEDIFF(minute, D_TS,GETDATE() )<30 
     group by I_ID_NAVE
```

The error is

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 Column 'posizioni.F_LATPRIMI' is
>   invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an
>   aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Add these to the GROUP BY `F_LATPRIMI ,F_LONPRIMI`

Comment: Why GROUP BY when no aggregate functions? What are you trying to do?

Comment: if i do" group by I_ID_NAVE ,F_LATPRIMI ,F_LONPRIMI"
 the query give me many rows end  i want only one row from any I_ID_NAVE

Answer (score 4):

I think what you are looking for is not `GROUP BY` rather `ROW_NUMBER()` function like

```
select  I_ID_NAVE,
F_LATPRIMI ,
F_LONPRIMI
from (
    select 
        imo,[N_ident_seguenziale], I_ID_NAVE, 
        F_LATPRIMI ,F_LONPRIMI,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY I_ID_NAVE ORDER BY I_ID_NAVE) AS rn
    from    
        navi inner join [ESTERNALIZZAZIONE_FASCICOLINAVE]
    ON [ESTERNALIZZAZIONE_FASCICOLINAVE].[I_ID_NAVE] = navi.[N_ident_seguenziale]) tabimo
join posizioni p on p.[I_ID_NAVE] = tabimo.[N_ident_seguenziale]
where DATEDIFF(minute, D_TS,GETDATE() ) < 30
and rn = 1;
```

Comment: give me this error "Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
The multi-part identifier "posizioni.I_ID_NAVE" could not be bound."

Comment: @LucaBigoni, see edit in answer if that helps. Anyways, your posted query was bit confusing ad to from where columns are fetched.

Answer (score 0):

in MsSql when using an Group By, all other columns need to be in an aggregate function (like MAX(), etc).
So maybe what you want is to delete the last row     `group by I_ID_NAVE`.

What do you really want?
Please explain to us so we can help

If you "want the last F_LATPRIMI and F_LONPRIMI from anyI_ID_NAVE"
use the "Last"-Aggregate-function:

```
select  I_ID_NAVE  ,LAST(F_LATPRIMI) ,LAST(F_LONPRIMI)
from(
    select 
        distinct imo,[N_ident_seguenziale]
    from    
        navi  
        inner join
        [ESTERNALIZZAZIONE_FASCICOLINAVE]
    ON
        [ESTERNALIZZAZIONE_FASCICOLINAVE].[I_ID_NAVE]=navi.[N_ident_seguenziale]
) as tabimo
inner join
    posizioni 
    on
    posizioni.[I_ID_NAVE]=tabimo.[N_ident_seguenziale] 

 where 
     DATEDIFF(minute, D_TS,GETDATE() )<30 
     group by I_ID_NAVE
```

Comment: i want the last F_LATPRIMI and F_LONPRIMI from anyI_ID_NAVE

Comment: please provide database schema for columns  F_LATPRIMI, F_LONPRIMI and I_ID_NAVE

Comment: "Use the Last Aggregate-function" Question is tagged sql-server?

Comment: Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 1
'LAST' is not a recognized built-in function name.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.

Answer (score 0):

One should group by all the columns which is in the select clause...

```
select  I_ID_NAVE  ,F_LATPRIMI ,F_LONPRIMI
from(
select 
    distinct imo,[N_ident_seguenziale]
from    
    navi  
    inner join
    [ESTERNALIZZAZIONE_FASCICOLINAVE]
ON
    [ESTERNALIZZAZIONE_FASCICOLINAVE].[I_ID_NAVE]=navi.[N_ident_seguenziale]
) as tabimo
inner join
  posizioni 
   on
   posizioni.[I_ID_NAVE]=tabimo.[N_ident_seguenziale] 
 where 
 DATEDIFF(minute, D_TS,GETDATE() )<30 
 group by I_ID_NAVE,F_LATPRIMI ,F_LONPRIMI
```

Comment: i want the last F_LATPRIMI and F_LONPRIMI from anyI_ID_NAVE